# latest posts by author

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm using a WP plugin to show latest posts by author, the plugin shows the post as a bullet points list, I need it to be shown in two columns; is that doable by editing the plugin's php code?

```
function latest_posts_by_author( $array ) {
global $post;

$defaults = array(
     'author' => '',
     'show' => 5,
     'excerpt' => 'false',
     'post_type' => 'post'
);

// Sets default author if in loop or on single page.    
if( in_the_loop() || is_single() ){
    $author_id=$post->post_author;
    $defaults['author'] = get_the_author_meta( 'user_login', $author_id );
}

// Overrides defaults with shortcode settings and separates into individual varaibles.
extract( shortcode_atts( $defaults, $array ) );

// Checks to make sure an author has been set.
if( !empty( $author ) ){

    // Checks to see if there are multiple authors set.
    $comma = strpos( $author, ',' );
    if( $comma === false ) {

        // Gets the author data for a single author.
        $author_data = get_user_by( 'login', $author );
        if( !empty( $author_data ) ) {
            $args = array(
                'author' => $author_data->ID,
                'posts_per_page' => $show,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'post_type' => $post_type
            );
        }

    } else {

        // Gets the author data for multiple authors.
        $authors = explode( ',', $author  );
        $author_data = '';
        foreach( $authors as $author_login ){
            $user = get_user_by( 'login', $author_login );
            $author_data .= $user->ID . ',';
        }

        $args = array(
            'author' => $author_data,
            'posts_per_page' => $show,
            'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
        );
    }

    // Gets posts form database
    $author_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Displays posts if available
    if( $author_query ) {
        $html = '';
        $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_list_before', $html );
        $html .= '<ul class="latestbyauthor">';
        while ( $author_query->have_posts() ) : $author_query->the_post();
            $html .= '<li>';
            $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_link_before', $html );

            // Displays a link to the post, using the post title
            $html .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '" title="' . get_the_title() . '">';
            $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_title_before', $html );
            $html .= apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_title', get_the_title() );
            $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_title_after', $html );
            $html .= '</a>';
            $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_link_after', $html );

            // Displays the post excerpt if "excerpt" has been set to true
            if($excerpt == 'true'){
                $html .= '<p>' . apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() ) . '</p>';
            }

            $html .= '</li>';
        endwhile;
        $html .= '</ul>';
        $html = apply_filters( 'latestbyauthor_list_after', $html );
    }

    // Resets Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();

    // Returns the results
   return $html;
}
```

}
add_shortcode('latestbyauthor', 'latest_posts_by_author');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the offset parameter.

Basically do 2 separate queries, the first showing however many you like then the next use 'offset'=> x in the parameters to offset the next one by 5.

e.g. for the first 5:

`$defaults = array(
     'author' => '',
     'show' => 5,
     'excerpt' => 'false',
     'post_type' => 'post'
);`

for the second:

`$defaults = array(
     'author' => '',
     'show' => 5,
     'excerpt' => 'false',
     'post_type' => 'post',
     'offset'=> 5
);`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts#Posts_list_with_offset

edit: to make it work you can just copy the whole function and make a new one with a different function name and shortcode name. In the second just offset it by how many you like this way you can call both shortcodes and you will have 2 lists with 5 posts in each.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I still have one issue that it is showing same results.
Once again, thanks for your help

Comment: No problem. What results are you expecting, and from what?